# How can i create a new document and insert Ooxml into that document from an add-in using office-js

Tags: ms-word, office-js

In an add-in im working on I've pulled Ooxml from an open document and i want to save that specific Ooxml to a new document.

Ive done the following to create a new document as Juan Balmori says in this SO post.
[How to open new word docx document in word add in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913645/how-to-open-new-word-docx-document-in-word-add-in)

```
function onaddOpenDoc() {
        Word.run(function (context) {
          // this getDocumentAsBase64 assumes a valid base64-encoded docx file
            var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument(getDocumentAsBase64());
            context.load(myNewDoc);

            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    myNewDoc.open();
                    context.sync();
                }).catch(function (myError) {
                    //otherwise we handle the exception here!
                    showNotification("Error", myError.message);
                })

        }).catch(function (myError) { showNotification("Error", myError.message); });
    }
```

A new file is created and opened, but i cant interact with the new file.
I've tried getting the myNewDoc.body and .insertOoxml() , but i get this message in the browser version.

> Error The action isn’t supported by Word in a browser. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.

The desktop version just opens a new file and does nothing.

My question boils down to, is there any way for me to interact with the body of a document that was created with context.application.createDocument() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the things you're looking for are still in Beta and not publicly released. See the [`DocumentCreated` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.documentcreated?view=word-js-preview) in the documentation.

The properties are listed, but when you scroll down you'll see the message

> This API is provided as a preview for developers and may change based
>   on feedback that we receive. Do not use this API in a production
>   environment.

It seems it will be in the next API requirement set (currently [ API set: WordApiHiddenDocument 1.4 ])